# Can you identify the set for these two LEGO bags?

Tags: set-identification, minifigures, set-numbering

[image: Bag 6 Front][image: Bag 6 Back] [image: Bag 8 Back]
[image: Bag 8 Front]

Looking to identify the following 2 bags

1. Bag 6    identifying possible help = 741R7  2015 Lego Group  135149
2. Bag 8    identifying possible help = 142R7  2015 Lego Group  135149

I am hoping the minifig heads might help.

Let me know what you experts think.  I just randomly found in my stash.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is set # [70909-1: Batcave Break-In](https://brickset.com/sets/70909-1/Batcave-Break-In)

[image]

Based on

[Plate, Modified 10 x 10 Octagonal Open Center](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=6063&idColor=85#T=C&C=85)

and

[Hips and Legs with Jacket Tails Pattern](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=970c00pb0596&idColor=1#T=C&C=1)

Comment: PERFECTION!  I can 100% match up the parts to this set.   You are amazing.  Thank you!